# Order list woocommerce Orders based on meta for custom status

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying create custom status called "Priority Order" when the product change status to "Priority Order" will automatically add post meta called `_priority_list` numeric based on how much orders set to priority orders, my questions is how to make default order list using meta `_priority_list`? here is my current code:

```
function filter_priority_orders() {
    global $pagenow;
    $qv = &$query->query_vars;

    if ( $pagenow == 'edit.php' && isset($qv['post_status']) && $qv['post_status'] == 'wc-priority-order' ) {            
        $query->set('meta_key', '_priority_list');
        $query->set('order_by', '_priority_list');
    }

    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_priority_orders' );
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem myself, thanks

```
function filter_priority_orders($query) {
    global $pagenow;
    $qv = $query->query_vars;

    if ( $pagenow == 'edit.php' && 
        isset($qv['post_status']) && $qv['post_status'] == 'wc-priority-order' && 
        isset($qv['post_type']) && $qv['post_type'] == 'shop_order' ) 
        {            
        $query->set('meta_key', '_priority_list');
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
        $query->set('order', 'ASC' );
    }

    return $query;
}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_priority_orders' );
```